# <F5> in vim-latex doesn't expand environment

Tags: environments, vim, vim-latex

I'm new to vim-latex and have been reading some tutorials. I've noticed that the behaviour of the <kbd>F5</kbd> on my machine is rather different from what the tutorials tell me.

I'm supposed to expect <kbd>F5</kbd> to expand an environment (if the name of the env is typed) or to select from a list in order to expand.

However, all I am getting `\usepackage{name of environment}` being returned, which doesn't make sense to me of course since I'm trying to add environment tags and not a package.

Why is there such a deviation from the expected behaviour?

Comment: Which operation system are you using? Windows, Linux/Unix, Mac, ...? I noticed that the Vim shortcuts under Windows are different as under Linux, which is where Vim comes from.

Comment: i'm running on ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press <kbd>F5</kbd> when the cursor is located outside `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, latex-suite lets you add packages, i.e. it inserts `\usepackage` statements. Moving the cursor inside the document section should lead to the desired behavior.

Comment: argh can't believe i made such a stupid mistake haha! trying to add environments after \end{document}!

thanks!

Comment: Oh no sorry to disappoint. I was a little hasty in accepting the answer but turns out the problem is still there even when I try it within the document tags.

Comment: turns out the issue is that the template had some erroneous tags which led vim-latex to believe that i was outside the document tags. 

in a way you were right so I'm still gonna give you the vote.

Comment: I'm glad to hear my guess was kind of helpful. It's true that latex-suite can easily be tricked by (broken) TeX/LaTeX constructs it doesn't expect at a specific location. Nonetheless, it usually does a great job.